# No virtual method setTokenProvider

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I don't know where the problem is, please help me

```
        E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.max.rm.marsol, PID: 32643
        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setTokenProvider(Lcom/google/firebase/internal
        /InternalTokenProvider;)V in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes   
        (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.max.rm.marsol-      
        834zEDd9vmvm9wCsb1cQoQ==/base.apk)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.zzp.create(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$new$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:69)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1.get(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:53)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.initializeEagerComponents(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:158)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:563)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:304)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:268)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:253)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:51)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1940)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1915)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:45)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6791)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6338)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:238)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7099)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

---

ــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــ

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
   compileSdkVersion 28
   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.max.rm.marsol"
       minSdkVersion 18
       targetSdkVersion 28
       multiDexEnabled true
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
          // multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
   lintOptions {

       checkReleaseBuilds false

   }

}

dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
   implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
   implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
   implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
   implementation 'com.github.twinkle942910:monthyearpicker:0.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.3'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.3'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
   implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
   implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
   implementation 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4'
   implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.3'
   implementation 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
   implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:6.1.2'
   implementation 'com.craftman.cardform:cardform:0.0.2'
   implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:16.0.1'
   implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
   implementation('com.stripe:stripe-android:1.0.4@aar') {
       transitive = true
   }
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
//com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files 3.1.4
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you find the answer? @Zeezoo

Answer (score 0):

change your firebase dependencies to this

```
implementation `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.5`
implementation `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0`
implementation `com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.2`
```